# How can I remove tabBarLabel for Individual tabs and placing only tabBarIcon in tabnavigation in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigationbar, tabbar, react-navigation

[This is the HomeScreen.js code which has import of Directory.js as one of the tab in tabBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx8et.png)

[This is Directory.js code which shows both tabBarlabel and tabBarIcon both on the Homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FzES.png)

[This is how it looks on android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0bbN.png)

I want to set showLabel=false on the individual tabs. but it doesn't works.
I just want to have Directory Icon, not the both label as well icon on it..

Homescreen.js file code -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View, Image,Dimensions
} from 'react-native';


import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ChatScreen from './ChatScreen.js';
import TaskScreen from './TaskScreen.js';
import FormScreen from './FormScreen.js';
import Directory from './Directory.js';
import Menu from './Menu.js';

const initialLayout = {
  height: 0,
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
};

var MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator ({
  Directory:  {screen: Directory},
  ChatScreen: {screen: ChatScreen},
  TaskScreen: {screen: TaskScreen},
  FormScreen: {screen: FormScreen},
  Menu:       {screen: Menu},
 },
 {
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
  animationEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    inactiveTintColor: '#9fffa9',
    activeTintColor: '#ffffff',
    showIcon: true,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#00dc17',
    },
    labelStyle:{
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: '400',
      fontFamily: 'WorkSans-SemiBold',
    },
    tabStyle: {

    },
    indicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor : '#fff',
      height : 2
    }
  },
}
);

MainScreenNavigator.navigationOptions ={
      header: false,

};

export default MainScreenNavigator;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your `Directory.js`:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarLabel: <View/>
})
```